# Error in dataframe *tmp* replacement has x data has y

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm a beginner in R. Here is a very simple code where I'm trying to save the residual term:

```
# Create variables for child's EA:

dat$cldeacdi <- rowMeans(dat[,c('cdcresp', 'cdcinv')],na.rm=T)
dat$cldeacu <- rowMeans(dat[,c('cucresp', 'cucinv')],na.rm=T)

# Create a residual score for child EA:

dat$cldearesid <- resid(lm(cldeacu ~ cldeacdi, data = dat))
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cldearesid, value = c(-0.18608488908881,  : 
  replacement has 366 rows, data has 367
```

I searched for this error but couldn't find anything that could resolve this. Additionally, I've created the exact same code for mom's EA, and it saved the residual just fine, with no errors. I'd be grateful if someone could help me resolve this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have a feeling you have `NA`s in your data. Look at this example:

```
#mtcars data set
test <- mtcars
#adding just one NA in the cyl column
test[2, 2] <- NA

#running linear model and adding the residuals to the data.frame
test$residuals <- resid(lm(mpg ~ cyl, test))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "residuals", value = c(0.382245430809409,  : 
  replacement has 31 rows, data has 32
```

As you can see this results in a similar error to yours.

As a validation:

```
length(resid(lm(mpg ~ cyl, test)))
#31
nrow(test)
#32
```

This happens because `lm` will run `na.omit` on the data set prior to running the regression, so if you have any rows with NA these will get eliminated resulting in fewer results.

If you run `na.omit` on your `dat` data set (i.e. `dat <- na.omit(dat)` at the very beginning of your code then your code should work.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that when I run na.omit it wipes out my dataset, as in - 0 observations of my variables... Why is that?

Comment: `na.omit` will remove the complete row from a data.frame if there is at least one column in that row with an `NA`. `lm` also does that since it calls `na.omit` internally. Make sure you exclude the columns you don't need at the regression before running `na.omit` .

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but maybe this can help someone else facing the same issue. To LyzandeR's point, check for NA's as a first line of defense. In addition, make sure that you don't have any factors in `x`, as this can also cause the error.

Comment: Hi Dawson, if I have 18 factor in the x, is it too much? If it is too much how can I do? And I think the tutorial has the same factor as I am.