# Including Date Format in a Data Frame

Tags: r, date

how can I transform a dataframe in a *month/day/year* format?

I'm using the following code to create a new column within my dataframe so that It contains the dates of each row from the metadata.

`meta.df.61.69$date = data.frame(date = str_extract(meta.df.61.69$Title,"\\d{1,2} \\w* \\d{4}"))`

When I run the code above, R returns me the following, as one can see in the first line in the picture: **17 JUNE 1961**

Essentially, how can I transform It in a *month/day/year* format? Something like this: *06/17/1961* instead of **17 JUNE 1961**.Thanks!

The return of `dput(head(meta.df.61.69$date))` is `structure(list(date = c("17 JUNE 1961", "19 JUNE 1961", "20 JUNE 1961",  "21 JUNE 1961", "22 JUNE 1961", "23 JUNE 1961")), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")`

Attached is a screenshot of my dataframe:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Date class [as.Date()] has options to specify format of the date.  While I generally prefer the format you have as unambiguous, your desired format would be specified by:

```
format="%m/%d/%Y"
```

There are lots of examples and tutorials out there via the googles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

as.Date(str_to_title("17 JUNE 1961"),"%d %B %Y")
```

Or in your case:

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

meta.df.61.69$date <- as.Date(str_to_title(meta.df.61.69$date),"%d %B %Y")
```

Comment: Hi @Marcos, thanks for your answer. When I run the code, ```meta.df.61.69$date <- as.Date(str_to_title(meta.df.61.69$date),"%d %B %Y")``` , however, R returns me only NA values in the date column and the following message: "In stri_trans_totitle(string, opts_brkiter = stri_opts_brkiter(locale = locale)) : argument is not an atomic vector; coercing". What should you recommend ?

Comment: If you can run the suggested code without errors, but you get an error using your data, then it will help to share an example of your data in a reproducible way (not as a screenshot). For example, you could include in your question the output of `dput(head(meta.df.61.69$date.date))`, which will create a data object exactly recreating the first six rows of your column.

Comment: hi @JonSpring, the output is ```structure(list(date = c("17 JUNE 1961", "19 JUNE 1961", "20 JUNE 1961", 
"21 JUNE 1961", "22 JUNE 1961", "23 JUNE 1961")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: I don't really understand what happend. I works perfect for me: `x <- structure(list(date = c("17 JUNE 1961", "19 JUNE 1961", "20 JUNE 1961",  "21 JUNE 1961", "22 JUNE 1961", "23 JUNE 1961")), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")

library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
x$date <- as.Date(str_to_title(x$date),"%d %B %Y")
`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample Data
# Edit: was previously 
# my_data <- structure(....
meta.df.61.69 <- structure(list(date.date = c("17 JUNE 1961", "19 JUNE 1961", "20 JUNE 1961",  "21 JUNE 1961", "22 JUNE 1961", "23 JUNE 1961")), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")


# Calculation assuming meta.df.61.69 is a data frame you have
meta.df.61.69$date_ISO8601 = lubridate::dmy(meta.df.61.69$date.date)
meta.df.61.69$date_formatted = format(meta.df.61.69$date_ISO8601 , "%m/%d/%Y")

> meta.df.61.69
          date date_ISO8601 date_formatted
1 17 JUNE 1961   1961-06-17     06/17/1961
2 19 JUNE 1961   1961-06-19     06/19/1961
3 20 JUNE 1961   1961-06-20     06/20/1961
4 21 JUNE 1961   1961-06-21     06/21/1961
5 22 JUNE 1961   1961-06-22     06/22/1961
6 23 JUNE 1961   1961-06-23     06/23/1961
```

Comment: Thank u @JonSpring, but how can I do It without manually selecting the dates? For example, without having to write c("17 JUNE 1961") etc.

My data covers the period from 1961 to 1978, so I can't do it manually :(

Comment: For simplicity I initially named my demonstration input table `my_data`, but it was meant to demonstrate what you want to do with `meta.df.61.69`. I've renamed the table in my example to make it explicit that this should work on your table as well, provided the rest of the data has consistent form.

Comment: I am still having errors @JonSpring. I will tell you step by step

first, I run the code ```meta.df.61.69$date = data.frame(date = str_extract(meta.df.61.69$Title,"\\d{1,2} \\w* \\d{4}"))```, which gives me the date format I want to change.

Next, I run the code you provided me: ```meta.df.61.69$date_ISO8601 = lubridate::dmy(meta.df.61.69$date)```

However, I receive the following message: "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." What should I do? Obs: meta.df.61.69 is a data frame I have

Comment: Edited to call the example column of extracted data `date.date` like your original post, does that help?

Comment: it shows the following message: ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date_ISO8601, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2484```

Comment: Sounds like same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232728/error-in-dataframe-tmp-replacement-has-x-data-has-y     Do you have lubridate installed? It seems to be saying that the `lubridate::dmy(meta.df.61.69$date.date)` vector has zero length, whereas `meta.df.61.69$date.date` has 2,484 elements.