# How to solve "replacement has 0 rows" when using the InteractionR function?

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I was trying to run a binary logistic regression with interaction effect between two variables with binary category.

My R code is below:

```
md1 <- glm(Diabetes_Cate_3 ~ Age_Years+factor(Gender)+
                Education_Year+factor(Marital_Status)+
                factor(Currently_Working)+factor(Smoked)+
                MUAC+BMI+factor(Wealth_Index)+
                Area*Year, family=binomial(link="logit"),
              data=Diabetes1)
```

Here:

```
  Dibetes_Cate_3 = "Diabetic" and "Nondiabetic"
  Area = "Rural" and "Urban"
  Year = "2011" and "2017"
```

I was trying to see the interaction of the risk of diabetes between Area and yeear adjusting all other factors.

While running interactionR function from the interactionR packages I was getting the follwoning error.

```
table_object = interactionR(md1, exposure_names = c("Area", "Year" ), 
                            ci.type = "mover",
                            ci.level = 0.95, em=FALSE, recode = T)
```

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, beta1, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8144
```

I will be grateful if anyone help fix this problem.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we would need to see (some of) your data and in indication of the packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the package here. The error you are getting is usually a result of your model fitting step and not the interaction estimation step. The error indicates you have `NAs` in your dataset that you should deal with first before fitting your model with the `glm()` function.

Under the hood, the `glm()` function runs `na.omit()` on the data before fitting the model which removes all rows with at least one missing value in any column. From the `glm()` arguments help page:

> na.action: a function which indicates what should happen when the data
> contain NAs. The default is set by the na.action setting of options,
> and is na.fail if that is unset. The ‘factory-fresh’ default is
> na.omit. Another possible value is NULL, no action. Value na.exclude
> can be useful.

This is better explained here with suggested fixes in a related question: [Error in dataframe *tmp* replacement has x data has y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232728/error-in-dataframe-tmp-replacement-has-x-data-has-y). It involves removing unrequired columns for the model with many `NAs` and ensuring factor levels are also not empty. Once you sort out the missing values issues you can then proceed with generating your interaction estimates using the package.